# reflection and type checking in scala

Tags: generics, scala, reflection

I have the following scala code

```
def invokeMethods(instance: AnyRef, clazz: Class[_]) {
   assert(clazz.isInstance(instance)   // <- is there a way to check this statically? 

   for {method <- clazz.getDeclaredMethods
        if shouldInvoke(method) // if the method has appropriate signature
       } method.invoke(instance)
}

// overload for common case
def invokeMethods(instance: AnyRef) {
   invokeMethods(instance, instance.getClass)
}
```

This works fine, but I wonder if the run time assertion could be replaced with compile time type checking.  My naive attempt is to change the first method to

```
def invokeMethods[T <:AnyRef](instance: T, clazz: Class[T]) {
   for {method <- clazz.getDeclaredMethods
        if shouldInvoke(method)
       } method.invoke(instance)
}
```

but I get a compilation error on the second method because instance.getClass returns a Class[_] instead of Class[T].  Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The following compiles, is it what you're looking for?

```
object Test {
   def shouldInvoke(m: java.lang.reflect.Method) = true
   def invokeMethods[T <:AnyRef](instance: T, clazz: Class[_ <: T]) {
     for {method <- clazz.getDeclaredMethods
       if shouldInvoke(method)
     } method.invoke(instance)
   }

   def invokeMethods[T <: AnyRef](instance: T) {
     invokeMethods(instance, instance.getClass)
   }
}
```

Comment: This is close.  But consider the following scenario: class A; class B extends A{def foo(){}}; the code you proposed allows me to invoke Test.invokeMethods[A](new A, classOf[B]), which will cause a run time exception.  My question is whether this can be checked at compile time.